# CEC complaining without monitor

Tags: openelec

I've enabled debbuging in OpenELEC through SSH into my Raspberry Pi. I have no monitor connected and every time I check `kodi.log` I see that CEC is complaining about it. What can I do?

```
22:26:37 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not start CEC communications
22:26:37 T:2954884160   ERROR: OpenConnection - could not opening a connection to the CEC adapter
22:26:47 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:47 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:47 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 1)
22:26:48 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:48 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:48 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 2)
22:26:49 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:49 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:49 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 3)
22:26:50 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:50 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:50 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 4)
22:26:51 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:51 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:51 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 5)
22:26:52 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:52 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:52 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 6)
22:26:53 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:53 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:53 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 7)
22:26:54 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:54 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:54 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 8)
22:26:55 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:55 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:55 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 9)
22:26:56 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(E) returned invalid arg (8)
22:26:56 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - Open - vc_cec could not be initialised
22:26:56 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not open a connection (try 10)
22:26:57 T:2954884160   ERROR: CecLogMessage - could not start CEC communications
22:26:57 T:2954884160   ERROR: OpenConnection - could not opening a connection to the CEC adapter
```

Comment: Ok, I've solved it by editing `config.txt` and enabling `hdmi_force_hotplug`, however I can't remount `/flash` to read-only. I do `mount /flash -o remount,ro` then reboot and it is still writable.

Comment: try mount -o remount,ro /flash

Answer (score 2):

From [Disable CEC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26302#p238772):

> http://elinux.org/RPiconfig
>
> Add `hdmi_ignore_cec=1` to `/boot/config.txt`
>
> I thought CEC doesn't do anything anyway unless running something like
>   XBMC. But I have both a Pi and Ubuntu Linux on my desktop PC connected
>   to my HDTV, so the Pi does not actually turn my TV on/off. And the
>   only time my Pi pays any attention to my TV remote is when running
>   Raspbmc.